# Getting a Listing Count

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, label

Hello everyone I seem to be having a issue with this for loop I am trying to create. I want this for loop to webscrap a website and gather all the names of a specific item then atm it prints it into the consule.

```
    html_url = requests.get(twelve_gauge_url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_url, "lxml")
    trueshotgunclubs = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-list-data-box-main trueshotgunclub.com')
    sharkcoastals = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-list-data-box-main sharkcoasttactical.com')
    ammodepots = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-list-data-box-main ammunitiondepot.com')
    justincaseammos = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-list-data-box-main justincaseammo.com')

    for trueshotgunclub in trueshotgunclubs:
        trueshotgunclub_ammo_name = trueshotgunclub.find('span', class_='description').text
        trueshotgunclub_ammo_grain = trueshotgunclub.find('div', class_='grains').text
        trueshotgunclub_ammo_price = trueshotgunclub.find('div', class_='price').text

        

        print(f"-----------------------------------------------------------")
        print(f"Ammo Name: {trueshotgunclub_ammo_name}")
        print(f"Ammo Grain: {trueshotgunclub_ammo_grain}")
        print(f"{trueshotgunclub_ammo_price}")
        # print(f"For more info about this handgun, Visit {ammo_desc_url}")
        print(f"------------------------------------------------------------")

        label.configure(text=get_ammo_name(trueshotgunclub_ammo_name))
```

Everything seems to be working so far as I want it to do. Now what I want it to do is create a listing counter that goes up everytime it gets a new trueshotgunclub_ammo_name so that I can use this counter to make labels to print the info on instead of printing it in the consule. If there is a way to just make a new label with trueshotgunclub_ammo_name, trueshotgunclub_ammo_grain and trueshotgunclub_ammo_price that would be much better and what I am trying to attempt to do. I have been trying to figure this out for about a month now and I figured it was time to ask for some help. Thank you all in advance.